# Facebook Ads how to see each conversion value or load the other conversion parameters?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-ads-api, facebook-conversions-api

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I have manually added the fb tracking code for leads inside an ajax form success function so when someone registers on the website this code is triggered:

```
fbq('track', 'Lead', {
    content_name: registered_user,
    content_category: registered_id,
    value: registerd_id,
    currency: 'GBP'
});
```

Inside FB Manager I can see the value (registered_id) under the "Leads Conversion Value" column but how can I see the value for each conversion? Currently it adds up all the conversion values together.

The only time I can see the values separately is when I am in the "test events" under data sources. Outside of that I can't figure out how to see the values for each conversion.

[image]

FYI, the leads don't actually have a GBP value so not sure this is the best way to do what I want. Ideally instead of sending a GBP value I want to just send a registered ID. Is it possible to see an unique ID for each conversion in the FB Ads Manager or FB Ads Reporting?

The leads value should actually be 1 but I'm using the registered ID because I can't see how to load the registered ID from content_category.

When I search the FB table columns for the other parameters (content_name and content_category) they don't come up.

If anyone can advise it would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance